# Select a single line of text within an element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I've found a lot of solutions for selecting the entire contents of an element using various forms of `onclick="this.select()"`, but is it possible to use javascript to select a single line from within an element `onclick`?

For example, I'm writing a Linux guide that involves many bash commands inside `<pre>` and `<code>` tags, and I don't want the user to have to click and drag to select each command line by line, because this becomes tedious after a few dozen rows. But, I also don't want to separate each command into it's own element that could be used for a selection event.

Example of the code block:

```
<pre><code>
sudo apt-get install foo
cd /etc/bar
sudo cp baz.conf baz.local
sudo nano baz.local
</code></pre>
```

I'd like the user to be able to just single-click on a line to select it, but there are no classes or id's to use. I'd also like this to apply to any `<pre><code>` block on the page, not just a particular one. A jQuery solution would be fine.

Is this possible?

Comment: The solution I've found is to wrap each line in a span, but this isn't very elegant and is a lot of overhead. I really don't know where to start in trying to look at an element line by line with javascript. I'd welcome a nudge in the write direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the lines and multiply it with the current vertical mouse divider of the code element (e.g. 0.5 if you are in the middle of the element).

This is the corresponding code fragment:

```
Math.floor(lines.length * (y/height))
```

A **jQuery plugin** based on this idea can be coded like this:

```
jQuery.fn.lineSelection = function(options) {
    var _this = this,
        height = null,
        lines = this.text().split('\n'),
        textChanged = false;

    // remove first empty lines (optional)
    while(lines[0] == '') {
        textChanged = true;
        lines.shift();
    }
    // remove last empty lines
    while(lines[lines.length-1] == '') {
        textChanged = true;
        lines.pop();
    }
    if(textChanged) {
        this.text(lines.join('\n'));
    }
    height = this.height();

    this.on('click', function() {
        var y = event.offsetY,
            // now use the described formula
            lineIndex = Math.floor(lines.length * y/height),
            line = lines[lineIndex];

        _this.trigger('lineClicked', [line, lineIndex]);
    });

    if(options.lineClicked) {
        this.on('lineClicked', options.lineClicked);
    }
};
```

The plugin can be used this way:

```
$('pre > code').lineSelection({
    lineClicked: function(event, text, index) {
        console.log(text, index);
    }
});
```

Also check out the working **[jsfiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bbevpL1/3/)**

Comment: This is great. I can see it printing to the console, but I'm can't get it to actually select text. I've tried incorporating a few other answers about selecting text, but they all rely on creating nodes from an element, like http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/WdeTM/4/
How can I actually select text with this in the browser?